# JavaScript date subtraction confusion

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following javascript. I basically want to calculate the time that passed between two dates. But the calculation for February 2015 seems to be wrong.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var d1 = new Date(2015,03,01,12);
            var d2 = new Date(2015,03,01,10);

            var d3 = d1 - d2;
            alert(d3 / 60000); //shows 120, which is correct

            var d1 = new Date(2015,03,01);
            var d2 = new Date(2015,02,01);

            d3 = new Date(d1 - d2);

            alert(d3/86400000); //shows 30.95 which is wrong
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you create `Date` from date difference (`d3 = new Date(d1 - d2);`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daylight savings must've kicked in during March

the figure should've been 30.958333333333332

as the other "answer" states, Months are zero based which explains more than 28 days, the rest is explained by the 1 hour loss due to DST

so, the FULL explanation is

- you are counting the number of days between 1st April and 1st of March = 31
- DST started, therefore you don't have 31 full days, you have 30.958333333333332 days in March

Comment: Correct answer is 28, not explainable with DST.

Comment: correct answer is 30.958333333333332, months are zero based and you lose an hour when DST kicks in

Comment: As the OP clearly says, he is trying to calculate the number of days in February. So the "correct" answer for the problem he is trying to solve is 28.

Comment: No, the OP states he wants to calculate the number of days between two dates, and the **example** he gives is (he thinks) February, but then counts the days in March and not only does it not show what he thought it should (28) it doesn't even show whole days

Comment: So he learned **two** things - months in javascript are zero based and daylight savings time is a thing to look out for when using javascript Date objects to perform maths on dates

Comment: "So he learned two things - months in javascript are zero based and daylight savings time is a thing to look out for when using javascript Date objects to perform maths on dates" - thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Indeed I learned two new things. It's much easier to perform date operations in C#. I read some articles regarding dates in JavaScript, but none of them mentioned that months are zero based.

Answer (score 2):

Month 3 is April. Month 2 is March. Months are zero-based.

```
var d1 = new Date(2015,02,01);     // March 1
var d2 = new Date(2015,01,01);     // February 1

d3 = new Date(d1 - d2);

alert(d3/86400000);                //shows 28, which is correct
```